# Why this custom function in Excel VBA not working properly. Is something wrong with the code or algorithm?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have written a code for the custom function to add numbers (greater than 15 digits) in Excel VBA. This is working fine if I am running this function for 1 time but gives an error when used several times. I am new to this field, SO ANY HELP WOULD REALLY BE APPRECIATED.

I have already written the code. Please have a look at it.

```
Public Function AddBigNumbers(n1 As String, n2 As String) As String
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
i3 = Int(Log(n1) / Log(10))
i4 = Int(Log(n2) / Log(10))
i5 = 0
i6 = 0

If i3 = i4 Then
    Dim Ad() As Long
    ReDim Ad(1 To i3 + 1) As Long
        For i2 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
            Ad(i2) = (Mid(n1, i2, 1))
        Next i2

i1 = 0
i2 = 0
     Dim Bd() As Long
     ReDim Bd(1 To i3 + 1) As Long
        For i2 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
            Bd(i2) = (Mid(n2, i2, 1))
        Next i2

Dim D() As Long
ReDim D(1 To i3 + 1) As Long

i1 = 0
     For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
        If Bd(i1) > Ad(i1) Then
            D(i1) = 1
        End If
     Next i1
i1 = 0
    For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
        If Bd(i1) = Ad(i1) Then
            D(i1) = 0
        End If
    Next i1
i1 = 0
    For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
        If Bd(i1) < Ad(i1) Then
            D(i1) = -1
        End If
    Next i1

i1 = 0
    For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
        If D(i1) > 0 Then i5 = n2 And i1 = i3 + 1 Else If D(i1) = 0 Then i1 = i1 Else i5 = n1
    Next i1
i1 = 0
    For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
        If D(i1) > 0 Then i6 = n1 And i1 = i3 + 1 Else If D(i1) = 0 Then i1 = i1 Else i6 = n2
    Next i1
End If

If i3 > i4 Then i5 = n1 Else i5 = n2
If i3 > i4 Then i6 = n2 Else i6 = n1


i7 = Int(Log(i5) / Log(10))
i8 = Int(Log(i6) / Log(10))

i1 = 0
i2 = 0
Dim A() As Long
ReDim A(1 To i7 + 1) As Long
    For i2 = 1 To i7 + 1 Step 1
        A(i2) = (Mid(i5, i2, 1))
    Next i2
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
    Dim B() As Variant
    ReDim B(1 To i7 + 1) As Variant
        If i7 > i8 Then
            For i1 = 1 To i7 - i8 Step 1
                B(i1) = 0
            Next i1

            For i2 = i7 - i8 + 1 To i7 + 1 Step 1
                B(i2) = Mid(i6, i2 - i7 + i8, 1)
            Next i2
        End If

         If i7 = i8 Then
             For i2 = 1 To i7 + 1 Step 1
                 B(i2) = Mid(i6, i2, 1)
             Next i2
         End If
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
    Dim C() As Variant
    ReDim C(1 To i7 + 1) As Variant
        For i2 = 1 To i7 + 1 Step 1
            C(i2) = CInt(A(i2)) + B(i2)
        Next i2

i1 = 0
i2 = 0
        For i2 = i7 + 1 To 2 Step -1
            C(i2 - 1) = C(i2 - 1) + Int(C(i2) / 10)
            C(i2) = C(i2) - 10 * Int(C(i2) / 10)
        Next i2
i9 = 0
i9 = Join(C, "")
'i9 = WorksheetFunction.Concat("'", Join(C, ""))
AddBigNumbers = i9
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
End Function
```

It is working fine if I run it for a single time (means if I use it for one time) but for multiple times, it is giving an error "#Value".

Comment: Please find attached screenshot of excel sheet throwing an error. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hny1dCMWUIUwQ19lX82sJ0GaggxydRKC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code (F8 in the VBA editor) and monitoring the locals window to see when running more than once what values are produced? 

OR if you add one or several Debug.Print lines within your function to print the values that assign to your sheet to the Immidiate window is another way you can check the value being produced.

Comment: what is `If D(i1) > 0 Then i5 = n2 And i1 = i3 + 1 Else If D(i1) = 0 Then i1 = i1 Else i5 = n1` supposed to do?

Comment: Basically D is the array which takes values {-1,0,1} if { B[i]>A[i],B[i]=A[i],B[i]<A[i] } respectively. This whole process is to decide which number is greater in case of equal number od digits in both numbers. i5 is assigned as greater number and i6 is smaller.

Comment: How big is big? If you overcome your limit here the log function will break as soon as one of the input strings are longer then 255 digits!

Comment: Numbers will be in a range of 1 to 61 digits. But it seems to break below 255 digits also not exactly sure why. PFA this screenshot for better understanding https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d0VqRb1m4oCRq3P9buJV1axOVxLg9ElG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the flaw is in two lines:

```
If D(i1) > 0 Then i5 = n2 And i1 = i3 + 1 Else If D(i1) = 0 Then i1 = i1 Else i5 = n1

If D(i1) > 0 Then i6 = n1 And i1 = i3 + 1 Else If D(i1) = 0 Then i1 = i1 Else i6 = n2
```

taking into account the first one and *translating* it into the *plain* `If` syntax, it would yield:

```
    If D(i1) > 0 Then
        i5 = n2 And i1 = i3 + 1
    Else
        If D(i1) = 0 Then
            i1 = i1
        Else
            i5 = n1
        End If
    End If
```

which as per your comment, should read:

```
    If D(i1) > 0 Then
        i5 = n2
        i1 = i3 + 1 ' to end loop
    Else
        If D(i1) = 0 Then
            i1 = i1
        Else
            i5 = n1
        End If
    End If
```

Furthermore:

- to exit the loop you want to use `Exit For` statement
- those two `For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1` loops can be melted together
- `i1 = i1` does nothing

and so you can rewrite those two loops in one single loop:

```
    For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
        If D(i1) > 0 Then
            i5 = n2
            i6 = n1
            Exit For
        ElseIf D(i1) < 0 Then
            i5 = n1
            i6 = n2
        End If
    Next i1
```

Finally, adding explicit variables declaration and some other optimizations, the whole code would result in the following:

```
Public Function AddBigNumbers(n1 As String, n2 As String) As String
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, i3 As Long, i4 As Long
    Dim i5 As Variant, i6 As Variant
    Dim i7 As Long, i8 As Long

    i3 = Int(Log(n1) / Log(10))
    i4 = Int(Log(n2) / Log(10))
    i5 = 0
    i6 = 0

    Select Case True
        Case i3 = i4
            ReDim Ad(1 To i3 + 1) As Long
            ReDim Bd(1 To i3 + 1) As Long
            For i2 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
                Ad(i2) = (Mid(n1, i2, 1))
                Bd(i2) = (Mid(n2, i2, 1))
            Next

            For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1
                If Bd(i1) > Ad(i1) Then
                    i5 = n2
                    i6 = n1
                    Exit For
                ElseIf Bd(i1) <= Ad(i1) Then
                    i5 = n1
                    i6 = n2
                End If
            Next

        Case i3 > i4
            i5 = n1
            i6 = n2

        Case Else
            i5 = n2
            i6 = n1
    End Select


    i7 = Int(Log(i5) / Log(10))
    i8 = Int(Log(i6) / Log(10))

    Dim A() As Long
    ReDim A(1 To i7 + 1) As Long
    For i2 = 1 To i7 + 1
        A(i2) = (Mid(i5, i2, 1))
    Next

    Dim B() As Variant
    ReDim B(1 To i7 + 1) As Variant
    Select Case True
        Case i7 > i8
            For i1 = 1 To i7 - i8
                B(i1) = 0
            Next

            For i2 = i7 - i8 + 1 To i7 + 1
                B(i2) = Mid(i6, i2 - i7 + i8, 1)
            Next
        Case i7 = i8
            For i2 = 1 To i7 + 1
                B(i2) = Mid(i6, i2, 1)
            Next
    End Select

    Dim C() As Variant
    ReDim C(1 To i7 + 1) As Variant
    For i2 = 1 To i7 + 1
        C(i2) = CInt(A(i2)) + B(i2)
    Next

    For i2 = i7 + 1 To 2 Step -1
        C(i2 - 1) = C(i2 - 1) + Int(C(i2) / 10)
        C(i2) = C(i2) - 10 * Int(C(i2) / 10)
    Next

    AddBigNumbers = Join(C, "")

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry sir, but I wanted to end the for loop as soon as D[i]>0, so that's why I wrote it like this "i5 = n2 And i1 = i3 + 1". Also, I don't know why it is throwing an error if I write like this If <Condition> Then 
                                 <Do something> 
                         Else 
                                 <Do something>
                         End if
It is throwing an error "Else without If". I tried everything, but this error is not resolving.
And this code worked fine in case of two numbers. It wouldn't be working if the code is wrong.

Comment: _"I wanted to end the for loop as soon as D[i]>0, so that's why I wrote it like this "i5 = n2 And i1 = i3 + 1""_ see edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. Worked like a charm. Can you please tell me where I was doing wrong?

Comment: `i5 = n2 And i1 = i3 + 1` is a valid statement indeed but it outputs a `Boolean` result (i.e.: `True` if `i5 = n2` _and_ at the same time `i1 = i3 + 1`, `False` otherwise) only.  While if you want to write two statements (i.e.: the statement `i5 = n2` and the statement `i1 = i3 + 1`) you have to write them in two different line, or in the same line separated by a colon (i.e.: `i5 = n2 : i1 = i3 + 1`)

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks for your valuable input.

Comment: @VineetMangal, you are welcome. You may want to see edited answer for a more optimized code

Comment: Sorry to bother you sir - @DisplayName - but can please have a look at this new question. I got the almost same error this time also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405255/an-error-is-coming-when-i-am-using-this-custom-function-multiplybignumbers-in

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.

```
Function SumBigNumbers(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String

    Dim n1 As Double, n2 As Double

    n1 = CDbl(s1)
    n2 = CDbl(s2)
    SumBigNumbers = CStr(n1 + n2)
End Function
```

The code simply converts the two strings of long numbers to actual numbers, adds them up and converts the result to string. VBA will return a string of a number in scientific notation. Note, however, that this is only for display purposes. Internally it's a normal (if long) number.

The conversion to something readable takes place, therefore, after the result has been calculated, i.e. in the calling procedure.

```
Private Sub CallSum()

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(16, 1)
        .Value = SumBigNumbers("12345678987654321", "34567890123987654")
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
End Sub
```

As it turns out, a simple NumberFormat will do the job. I just wonder if this will work with much bigger numbers the way it does in my example.

Comment: Sorry for wrong syntax and indentation. But my logic is absolutely true. According to your code, if I enter two numbers {3456784,8765459} then I get {'91111374} as a result which is wrong because the sum of both numbers is {12222243}.

Comment: Since from start, my logic was extract all the digits of both the numbers and store them in an array. This screenshot might help with the logic I am trying to apply https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cj-3SYCNS1yQz5lDO-7vGXyXJMkOQq7V/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The algorithm you implemented does not relate to the addition theorem which you showed in the picture above!

Answer (score 0):

If you dim i1 .. i9 as integer you will find that your algorithm breaks within an integer limit. Whenever you assign the input strings n1 or n2 to one of the variables ix you risk to break your code (you loose the ability to add bigger numbers).

```
...
If D(i1) > 0 Then i5 = n2 And i1 = i3 + 1 Else If D(i1) = 0 Then i1 = i1 Else i5 = n1  'line 47
...
If D(i1) > 0 Then i6 = n1 And i1 = i3 + 1 Else If D(i1) = 0 Then i1 = i1 Else i6 = n2  'line 51
...
If i3 > i4 Then i5 = n1 Else i5 = n2                                                   'line 55
If i3 > i4 Then i6 = n2 Else i6 = n1                                                   'line 56
...
```

If you just want to solve a problem (up to 200 digits): use xnumbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNUMBERS)

If you want to learn to code: Use "Option Explicit" and use a lot of debug.print lines.
e.g `Debug.Print "Step x: "; i1; " "; i2; " "; i3; " "; i4; " "; i5; " "; i6; " "; i7; " "; i8; " "; i9`

Why don't you just add the input strings character by character?
(Ad(ix)+Bd(iX) and handle the overflow)

Answer (score 0):

The "addition theorem" acc to your picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hny1dCMWUIUwQ19lX82sJ0GaggxydRKC/view in pseudocode:

```
    'step 1: add every digit of the input strings
    'step 2: for each result above 10:
    'step 3:    reduce by 10 and add 1 to the result of the neighbour
```

Answer (score 0):

The "addition theorem" acc to your picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hny1dCMWUIUwQ19lX82sJ0GaggxydRKC/view in pseudocode:

```
    'step 1: add every digit of the input strings
    'step 2: for each result above 10:
    'step 3:    reduce by 10 and add 1 to the result of the neighbour
```

Your algorith breaks for longer strings (above ~300 digits):

[image]

```
Public Function AddBig(n1 As String, n2 As String) As String

Dim A(10000) As Integer
Dim B(10000) As Integer
Dim r(10000) As Integer
Dim iCt As Integer
Dim lenCt As Integer
Dim DebugStr As String
Dim Plus1 As Boolean

'Dim n1 As String, n2 As String

'n1 = Range("b3")
'n2 = Range("b6")

    For iCt = Len(n1) To 1 Step -1
        A(iCt) = Mid(n1, Len(n1) - iCt + 1, 1)
    Next iCt

    For iCt = Len(n2) To 1 Step -1
        B(iCt) = Mid(n2, Len(n2) - iCt + 1, 1)
    Next iCt

    lenCt = Application.Max(Len(n1), Len(n2))

    For iCt = lenCt To 1 Step -1
        r(iCt) = A(iCt) + B(iCt)
    Next iCt

    For iCt = 1 To lenCt
        If r(iCt) > 9 Then
            r(iCt) = r(iCt) - 10
            r(iCt + 1) = r(iCt + 1) + 1
            If iCt = lenCt Then Plus1 = True
        End If
        resultStr = r(iCt) & resultStr
    Next iCt
    If Plus1 Then resultStr = "1" & resultStr
    Debug.Print resultStr
    AddBig = resultStr
End Function
```