# An error is coming when I am using this custom function (MultiplyBigNumbers) in the worksheet. Is something wrong with code or syntax?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written code (Excel VBA Custom Function) for multiplication of big numbers and display the correct result in string format. But there seems to be something wrong with this code which I am unable to figure out.

image for better understanding of logic.

[image]

There are two cases shown in the above image. Matrix order will change according to no of digits. Also, Number 2 will be either 1 or 2 digits only, not more than that. Only Number 1 will be more than 20 or 30 digits.

I have already written the code.

```
Public Function MultiplyBigNumbers(n1 As String, n2 As String) As String
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, i3 As Long, i4 As Long
    Dim i5 As Variant, i6 As Variant
    Dim i7 As Long, i8 As Long



i3 = Int(Log(n1) / Log(10))
i4 = Int(Log(n2) / Log(10))
i5 = 0
i6 = 0

    Select Case True
        Case i3 = i4
            ReDim Ad(1 To i3 + 1) As Long
            ReDim Bd(1 To i3 + 1) As Long
            For i2 = 1 To i3 + 1 Step 1
                Ad(i2) = (Mid(n1, i2, 1))
                Bd(i2) = (Mid(n2, i2, 1))
            Next

            For i1 = 1 To i3 + 1
                If Bd(i1) > Ad(i1) Then
                    i5 = n2
                    i6 = n1
                    Exit For
                ElseIf Bd(i1) <= Ad(i1) Then
                    i5 = n1
                    i6 = n2
                End If
            Next

        Case i3 > i4
            i5 = n1
            i6 = n2

        Case Else
            i5 = n2
            i6 = n1
    End Select


    i7 = Int(Log(i5) / Log(10)) + 1
    i8 = Int(Log(i6) / Log(10)) + 1

i3 = 0
i4 = 0
    Dim A() As Long
    ReDim A(1, 1 To i7) As Long
        For i3 = 1 To i7 Step 1
            A(1, i3) = Mid(i5, i3, 1)
        Next i3
i3 = 0
i4 = 0
    Dim B() As Long
    ReDim B(1 To i7, 1 To i7 + i8 - 1) As Long

    If i8 = 2 Then
            For i3 = 1 To i7 Step 1
                For i4 = 1 To i7 + i8 - 1 Step 1
                    If i3 = i4 Then
                        B(i3, i4) = Mid(i6, 1, 1)
                    ElseIf i4 - i3 = 1 Then
                        B(i3, i4) = Mid(i6, 2, 1)
                    Else
                        B(i3, i4) = 0
                    End If
                Next i4
            Next i3
     Else
            For i3 = 1 To i7 Step 1
                For i4 = 1 To i7 + i8 - 1 Step 1
                    If i4 - i3 = 1 Then
                        B(i3, i4) = Mid(i6, 1, 1)
                    Else
                        B(i3, i4) = 0
                    End If
                Next i4
            Next i3
     End If

i3 = 0
i4 = 0
Dim k As Long
k = 0
    Dim D() As Long
    ReDim D(1, 1 To i7 + i8 - 1) As Long
        For i3 = 1 To i7 + i8 - 1 Step 1
            For k = 1 To i7 Step 1
                D(1, i3) = D(1, i3) + A(1, k) * B(k, i3)
            Next k
        Next i3
i3 = 0
i4 = 0
    For i3 = i7 + i8 - 1 To 2 Step -1
       D(1, i3 - 1) = D(1, i3 - 1) + Int(D(1, i3) / 10)
       D(1, i3) = D(1, i3) - 10 * Int(D(1, i3) / 10)
    Next i3

    Dim C() As Variant
    ReDim C(1 To i7 + i8 - 1) As Variant
        For i3 = 1 To i7 + i8 - 1 Step 1
            C(i3) = D(1, i3)
        Next i3

    MultiplyBigNumbers = Join(C, "")

End Function
```

Comment: "there seems to be something wrong" - please be more specific.

Comment: An error is coming when I am using this formula in the worksheet. PFA screenshot for more clarity. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKYQQ8kPWCy8B2zXRHjrs9eMxIoXXnFd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Log(n1) -> n1 is a string not a number??

Comment: But it was working in previous code.PFA the link to the previous function in which it was worked. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZBAd9aEac95ybIC2Uc4O3vtU6OSUZwzd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit that my `Log` math does not, if one wants to be highly technical, exist. However I trapped your error to be because this line of code is throwing an error: `i4 = Int(Log(n2) / Log(10))` when `n2=0`.

Here's a sample test to show:

```
Sub testiWishiKnewMathBetterThis()

'this will work
    MsgBox Log(500) / Log(10)

'this one won't.
    MsgBox Log(0) / Log(10)

End Sub
```

Here's a screen shot of the error you'll get:

[image: uh oh]

Comment: Sorry sir but n2 is not 0. Check this screenshot for more clarity. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKYQQ8kPWCy8B2zXRHjrs9eMxIoXXnFd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: VBA is throwing no error. The error is coming when I am using this function in the worksheet.

Comment: Sorry sir but yes it is... cell `A7` is indeed zero, or at least that is what excel is reading it as. In your spreadsheet, put `=Value(A7)=0` and you'll get `True`

Comment: @VineetMangal yes it is, you just aren't seeing it, which is why I included the screenshot...

Comment: My point is - Value in cells A3 & A4 is coming absolutely correct. After that, A5 & A6 showing garbage value and A7 is absolutely 0. There is something wrong with code which is why value in A5 & A6 is not coming correct. My question is why values in A5 & A6 is not coming correct?

Comment: Okay well the title of your question specifically directs attention to the ERROR, which only appears in cell A8 which is because A7 is zero. Sorry I couldn't read your mind. You might note that your previous two comments contesting my answer are false. This inaccuracy combined with your crackerjack personality may not yield the benevolence of many more experienced users. Best of luck with your formula.

Comment: No problem sir. Thanks for your time anyway. Do let me know if you find the correct solution to my problem.